# Azure Application Insights console logs format

Tags: azure, spring-boot, logging, logback, azure-application-insights

I am working on a spring-boot app that uses azure Application Insights.
I have a defined format for the logs that are shown in console that are configured with logback

```
<appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout>
            <Pattern>%d{ISO8601} %level class=%C{1.} %X{requestKey} msg=%msg%n%throwable </Pattern>
        </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="aiAppender"
              class="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logback.ApplicationInsightsAppender">
</appender>
```

the problem is that the logs that are shown in cosole by AI are shown as follows:

```
2020-01-10 08:47:58,089 INFO class=org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  msg=Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-01-10 08:47:58,802 INFO class=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext  msg=Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8435 ms
AI: INFO 10-01-2020 07:48:00.819+0000, 1(main): Agent is not running
```

I dont want to display AI: logs that way, I mean, I would like to change such traces formar as the same format defined in console appender:

```
2020-01-10 08:47:58,802 INFO class=com.microsoft.blabla.ApplicationInsights msg=Agent is not running
```

It is possible to change such traces format?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The format you see is internal AI debug logging format e.g.

```
    AI: INFO 10-01-2020 07:48:00.819+0000, 1(main): Agent is not running
```

**Currently this format cannot be changed.**

However, if you want to share a feedback please do it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-azure-monitor-application-insights) with additional details on the scenario you are trying to achieve which would allow the product team to evaluate the ask accordingly. Thank you